# Contribution to/towards/for

Tags: prepositions

According to OALD **contribution to/towards** is correct usage, but in the following sentence

> The country’s highest film honour, the Dadasaheb Phalke award, conferred for “outstanding **contribution for** the growth and development of Indian cinema” will be presented this year to Amitabh Bachchan.

**Contribution for** is used. Is that correct?

Comment: This is a simple preposition type of question, with the entire sentence / context included. What's potentially missing are the sources of the quote and OALD entry. There's no real reason to close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form "contribution to X" or "contribution towards X" is certainly the usual form in US or UK English. "contribution for" could be used to indicate the **purpose** of the contribution, rather than the thing contributed to, such as:

> Jones made a large contribution for feeding the hungry.

But this is not the construction in the question.

It may be that a phrase such as "outstanding contribution for the growth and development of Indian cinema” would be usual in Indian English, I don't know. It is certainly not natural in US English, nor, I think, in UK or Canadian English. But I expect that most fluent speakers of any variety of English would understand it correctly, and I hesitate to label it as "wrong". But I advise learners not to imitate this example.